# Calling cpp function from NodeJS which has argument const int16_t *bar but getting error unbound type

Tags: c++, node.js, ffi, n-api

I am trying to call CPP function from NodeJS

```
typedef struct foo {

    uint8_t     *data;
    int         dataSize;

} foo ;

foo *ExtractBar(const int16_t *bar);
```

I have tried nbind library in NodeJS. but getting unbound type error.

```
uint16 = Int16Array.from('12345');
uint16.fill(0);
lib.ExtractBar(uint16);
```

I have also tried ffi-napi npm module. but from that I was getting segmentation fault error.
can anyone help me please on how to pass correct argument from NodeJS code.
I am  not sure how to  create similar structure in NodeJS-

```
const int16_t *bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to have a reference to a variable as JavaScript is a garbage collected language.

[Specifically to nbind, have a look at this](https://github.com/charto/nbind#type-conversion) and [this](https://github.com/charto/nbind#buffers). You want to pass from NodeJS an buffer of uint16 so you could use `nbind::Buffer`.

Comment: Hi, I tried nbind::Buffer ---  int length = buf.length();
  unsigned char *data = buf.data();
  const int16_t *p = (int16_t *)data;
  lib.ExtractBar(p);    but not it is giving me segmentation fault error.